# Как заполнить строки DataFrame значениями из цикла?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

Каким образом вообще в принципе можно при анализе DataFrame в цикле, записывать в пустые ячейки столбца значения? Например, скажем:

```
df['now_I_can_write_total']
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('... .csv')

value_l = list(df['value'].values)

for i in range(len(df)):
    total = 1000
    if value_l[i] > 100:

        df['now_I_can_write_total'] = total

print(total)
```

Собственно:

```
df['now_I_can_write_total'] = total
```

определенно как не правильная запись.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе маленький (5-7 строк), но воспроизводимый пример входного датафрейма и результирующий фрейм, который вы хотите получить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно только вычислить значение на основе значения в другом столбце этой же строки, то можно с помощью `numpy.where()`:

```
In [85]: import pandas as pd

In [86]: import numpy as np  

In [87]: df
Out[87]: 
   idx  value
0    1     50
1    2    150
2    3    120
3    4     40
4    5    200

In [88]: df['now_I_can_write_total'] = np.where(df.value > 100, 1000, pd.NA)

In [89]: df
Out[89]: 
   idx  value now_I_can_write_total
0    1     50                  <NA>
1    2    150                  1000
2    3    120                  1000
3    4     40                  <NA>
4    5    200                  1000
```

Или, если нужны какие-то дополнительные манипуляции, применить свою функцию с помощью `apply()`:

```
In [103]: def calc_total(row): 
     ...:     total = 1000 
     ...:     if row.value > 100: 
     ...:         return total 
     ...:     return pd.NA 
     ...:

In [104]: df
Out[104]: 
   idx  value
0    1     50
1    2    150
2    3    120
3    4     40
4    5    200

In [105]: df['now_I_can_write_total'] = df.apply(calc_total, axis=1)

In [106]: df
Out[106]: 
   idx  value now_I_can_write_total
0    1     50                  <NA>
1    2    150                  1000
2    3    120                  1000
3    4     40                  <NA>
4    5    200                  1000
```

Если рассматривать ваш цикл, то для записи значения вам еще нужно указать индекс:

```
df.loc[i, 'now_I_can_write_total'] = total
```

```
In [116]: df
Out[116]: 
   idx  value
0    1     50
1    2    150
2    3    120
3    4     40
4    5    200

In [117]: value_l = list(df['value'].values)

In [118]: value_l
Out[118]: [50, 150, 120, 40, 200]

In [119]: for i in range(len(df)): 
     ...:     total = 1000 
     ...:     if value_l[i] > 100: 
     ...:         df.loc[i, 'now_I_can_write_total'] = total 
     ...:                                                                                

In [120]: df
Out[120]: 
   idx  value  now_I_can_write_total
0    1     50                    NaN
1    2    150                 1000.0
2    3    120                 1000.0
3    4     40                    NaN
4    5    200                 1000.0
```

Answer (score 4):

Без примеров данных трудно понять, что вы хотите сделать, но предположу, что вы хотите заполнить значения нового столбца следующим образом:

- если значение в столбце `value > 100` то заполняем столбец `now_I_can_write_total` значением `total`
- в противном случае заполняем `NaN`

Сделать это можно так (векторизированным способом, т.е. без циклов):

```
df.loc[df['value'] > 100, 'now_I_can_write_total'] = total
```